# What is the URL for using the Tooling API via SOAP?

Tags: api, soap-api, tooling-api

**What is the URL for using the Tooling API via SOAP?**

If I already have a valid Session Id I can start using the API directly: E.g.

- Enterprise API:
  https://*server*-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/**c**/27.0/*orgId*
- Partner API:
  https://*server*-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/**u**/27.0/*orgId*
- Metadata API:
  https://*server*-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/**m**/27.0/*orgId*
  Note this is easy to get using the [LoginResult.metadataServerUrl](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm)
- Apex API:
  https://*server*-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/**s**/27.0
- Tooling API:
  https://*server*-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/***?***/27.0/*orgId*

I've tried (as a guess) https://*server*-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/**t**/27.0/*orgId*, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my general development org, the end point described in the Tooling API WSDL is as follows. So you where close, not sure if the capital T makes a difference, it may.

> https://na11-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/T/27.0

If you goto the API page under Setup, you can download the **WSDL (Web Service Definition Language)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also found that the endpoint ```https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/T/35.0``` works for sandboxes in general.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

https://server-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/tooling/27.0/orgId

And here are some more characters to get over the 30 character minimum.